# No threaddump generated on kill -3

Tags: java, jvm, thread-dump

Is there a possibility that kill -3 / quit PID prints nothing i.e. an empty thread dump? We heard a story from a support engineer and was wondering if some experts could validate.

This is on Java 6_26 on RHEL 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only seen this when the server redirects to stdout, like JBoss, and stdout has been redirected to /dev/null because whoever set up the server thought that everything going to stdout was already going to a named log file.

Comment: Would it make any difference if we redirected the output to a file in the command itself: kill -3 PID > dump

Comment: As I recall, redirecting the output from the kill -3 did not work and we had to change our startup script (to no longer redirect)

Comment: A bit late, but I have found that you may be able to use 'jstack' to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The console output of JVM thread dump on some servers is redirected to a log file. In case of Tomcat Server it is usually Catalina.out.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the behavior you describe in a standalone Java application (Oracle JDK 1.6.20+, Linux), but I can't tell how to reproduce this behavior consistently. It may have been after an `OutOfMemoryError` in one of the threads but I'm not sure any more.

I also think that what I got was not just an empty dump, but that the command actually froze and didn't return me to the shell until I pressed ctrl+C after waiting for a while. Either way, I'm sure that the behavior of `jstack` was exactly the same as of `kill -3`. When it happened, the app was in such bad shape that it didn't react to normal `kill` and only `kill -9` worked on it. There were no redirections and under normal circumstances the app reacted to `kill -3` as it should.